# How to determine a certain pattern with canvas created shapes?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.5

In tkinter, python, I'm currently working on a game which is similar to 'Tic Tac Toe' where a player is meant to click a box and get 3 in a row, while facing an opponent. I've been working on doing this in python, but I'm unsure how I can get an output from when 3 boxes in a row are filled. Here's my code:

```
# Tic Tac Toe

# --------------------------- #
import random           
from tkinter import *  
# --------------------------- #

root = Tk()
root.title("Tic Tac Toe")
root.geometry("800x800")

canvas = Canvas(root, height = 700, width=700)
canvas.pack()

movesd = 0
done = False

rec1 = canvas.create_rectangle(100, 0, 200, 100, fill='white', tags="r1")
canvas.move(rec1, 100, 150)
rec2 = canvas.create_rectangle(100, 0, 200, 100, fill='white', tags="r2")
canvas.move(rec2, 200, 150)
rec3 = canvas.create_rectangle(100, 0, 200, 100, fill='white', tags="r3")
canvas.move(rec3, 300, 150)
rec4 = canvas.create_rectangle(100, 0, 200, 100, fill='white', tags="r4")
canvas.move(rec4, 100, 250)
rec5 = canvas.create_rectangle(100, 0, 200, 100, fill='white', tags="r5")
canvas.move(rec5, 200, 250)
rec6 = canvas.create_rectangle(100, 0, 200, 100, fill='white', tags="r6")
canvas.move(rec6, 300, 250)
rec7 = canvas.create_rectangle(100, 0, 200, 100, fill='white', tags="r7")
canvas.move(rec7, 100, 350)
rec8 = canvas.create_rectangle(100, 0, 200, 100, fill='white', tags="r8")
canvas.move(rec8, 200, 350)
rec9 = canvas.create_rectangle(100, 0, 200, 100, fill='white', tags="r9")
canvas.move(rec9, 300, 350)

rec1md = False
rec2md = False
rec3md = False
rec4md = False
rec5md = False
rec6md = False
rec7md = False
rec8md = False
rec9md = False

firstmovedone = False
secondgo = False
secondmovedone = False
thirdgo = False
thirdmovedone = False
fourthgo = False
fourthmovedone = False

def combinations():
    global done
    if movesd == 3:
        done = True
        label = Label(root, text="Congratulations! You Win!", font='Verdana, 50')
        label.pack()
    root.after(1, combinations)

def thirdmove():
    global fourthgo
    global thirdmovedone
    thirdmovedone = True
    global rec1md
    moves = ["rm1", "rm2", "rm3", "rm4", "rm5", "rm6"]
    firstrandom = random.choice(moves)
    if firstrandom == "rm1":
        if rec1md:
            thirdmove()
        else:
            rec1mf = canvas.create_rectangle(100, 0, 200, 100, fill='blue')
            canvas.move(rec1mf, 100, 150)
    if firstrandom == "rm2":
        if rec2md:
            thirdmove()
        else:
            rec2mf = canvas.create_rectangle(100, 0, 200, 100, fill='blue')
            canvas.move(rec2mf, 200, 150)
    if firstrandom == "rm3":
        if rec3md:
            thirdmove()
        else:
            rec3mf = canvas.create_rectangle(100, 0, 200, 100, fill='blue')
            canvas.move(rec3mf, 300, 150)
    if firstrandom == "rm4":
        if rec4md:
            thirdmove()
        else:
            rec4mf = canvas.create_rectangle(100, 0, 200, 100, fill='blue')
            canvas.move(rec4mf, 100, 250)
    if firstrandom == "rm5":
        if rec5md:
            thirdmove()
        else:
            rec5mf = canvas.create_rectangle(100, 0, 200, 100, fill='blue')
            canvas.move(rec5mf, 200, 250)
    if firstrandom == "rm6":
        if rec6md:
            thirdmove()
        else:
            rec6mf = canvas.create_rectangle(100, 0, 200, 100, fill='blue')
            canvas.move(rec6mf, 300, 250)
    if firstrandom == "rm7":
        if rec7md:
            thirdmove()
        else:
            rec7mf = canvas.create_rectangle(100, 0, 200, 100, fill='blue')
            canvas.move(rec7mf, 100, 350)
    if firstrandom == "rm8":
        if rec8md:
            thirdmove()
        else:
            rec8mf = canvas.create_rectangle(100, 0, 200, 100, fill='blue')
            canvas.move(rec8mf, 200, 350)
    if firstrandom == "rm9":
        if rec9md:
            thirdmove()
        else:
            rec9mf = canvas.create_rectangle(100, 0, 200, 100, fill='blue')
            canvas.move(rec9mf, 300, 350)
    fourthgo = True

def secondmove():
    global thirdgo
    global secondmovedone
    secondmovedone = True
    global rec1md
    moves = ["rm1", "rm2", "rm3", "rm4", "rm5", "rm6"]
    firstrandom = random.choice(moves)
    if firstrandom == "rm1":
        if rec1md:
            secondmove()
        else:
            rec1mf = canvas.create_rectangle(100, 0, 200, 100, fill='blue')
            canvas.move(rec1mf, 100, 150)
    if firstrandom == "rm2":
        if rec2md:
            secondmove()
        else:
            rec2mf = canvas.create_rectangle(100, 0, 200, 100, fill='blue')
            canvas.move(rec2mf, 200, 150)
    if firstrandom == "rm3":
        if rec3md:
            secondmove()
        else:
            rec3mf = canvas.create_rectangle(100, 0, 200, 100, fill='blue')
            canvas.move(rec3mf, 300, 150)
    if firstrandom == "rm4":
        if rec4md:
            secondmove()
        else:
            rec4mf = canvas.create_rectangle(100, 0, 200, 100, fill='blue')
            canvas.move(rec4mf, 100, 250)
    if firstrandom == "rm5":
        if rec5md:
            secondmove()
        else:
            rec5mf = canvas.create_rectangle(100, 0, 200, 100, fill='blue')
            canvas.move(rec5mf, 200, 250)
    if firstrandom == "rm6":
        if rec6md:
            secondmove()
        else:
            rec6mf = canvas.create_rectangle(100, 0, 200, 100, fill='blue')
            canvas.move(rec6mf, 300, 250)
    if firstrandom == "rm7":
        if rec7md:
            secondmove()
        else:
            rec7mf = canvas.create_rectangle(100, 0, 200, 100, fill='blue')
            canvas.move(rec7mf, 100, 350)
    if firstrandom == "rm8":
        if rec8md:
            secondmove()
        else:
            rec8mf = canvas.create_rectangle(100, 0, 200, 100, fill='blue')
            canvas.move(rec8mf, 200, 350)
    if firstrandom == "rm9":
        if rec9md:
            secondmove()
        else:
            rec9mf = canvas.create_rectangle(100, 0, 200, 100, fill='blue')
            canvas.move(rec9mf, 300, 350)
    thirdgo = True

def firstmove():
    global secondgo
    global firstmovedone
    firstmovedone = True
    global rec1md
    moves = ["rm1", "rm2", "rm3", "rm4", "rm5", "rm6"]
    firstrandom = random.choice(moves)
    if firstrandom == "rm1":
        if rec1md:
            firstmove()
        else:
            rec1mf = canvas.create_rectangle(100, 0, 200, 100, fill='blue')
            canvas.move(rec1mf, 100, 150)
    if firstrandom == "rm2":
        if rec2md:
            firstmove()
        else:
            rec2mf = canvas.create_rectangle(100, 0, 200, 100, fill='blue')
            canvas.move(rec2mf, 200, 150)
    if firstrandom == "rm3":
        if rec3md:
            firstmove()
        else:
            rec3mf = canvas.create_rectangle(100, 0, 200, 100, fill='blue')
            canvas.move(rec3mf, 300, 150)
    if firstrandom == "rm4":
        if rec4md:
            firstmove()
        else:
            rec4mf = canvas.create_rectangle(100, 0, 200, 100, fill='blue')
            canvas.move(rec4mf, 100, 250)
    if firstrandom == "rm5":
        if rec5md:
            firstmove()
        else:
            rec5mf = canvas.create_rectangle(100, 0, 200, 100, fill='blue')
            canvas.move(rec5mf, 200, 250)
    if firstrandom == "rm6":
        if rec6md:
            firstmove()
        else:
            rec6mf = canvas.create_rectangle(100, 0, 200, 100, fill='blue')
            canvas.move(rec6mf, 300, 250)
    if firstrandom == "rm7":
        if rec7md:
            firstmove()
        else:
            rec7mf = canvas.create_rectangle(100, 0, 200, 100, fill='blue')
            canvas.move(rec7mf, 100, 350)
    if firstrandom == "rm8":
        if rec8md:
            firstmove()
        else:
            rec8mf = canvas.create_rectangle(100, 0, 200, 100, fill='blue')
            canvas.move(rec8mf, 200, 350)
    if firstrandom == "rm9":
        if rec9md:
            firstmove()
        else:
            rec9mf = canvas.create_rectangle(100, 0, 200, 100, fill='blue')
            canvas.move(rec9mf, 300, 350)
    secondgo = True

def r1m(event):
    combinations()
    global firstmovedone
    if firstmovedone == False:
        global movesd
        global rec1md
        rec1md = True
        rec1m = canvas.create_rectangle(100, 0, 200, 100, fill='red')
        canvas.move(rec1m, 100, 150)
        canvas.delete(rec1)
        root.after(1000, firstmove)
        movesd += 1
    else:
        if secondgo == True:
            global movesd
            global rec1md
            rec1md = True
            rec1m = canvas.create_rectangle(100, 0, 200, 100, fill='red')
            canvas.move(rec1m, 100, 150)
            canvas.delete(rec1)
            root.after(1000, firstmove)
            movesd += 1


def r2m(event):
    combinations()
    if firstmovedone == False:
        global movesd
        global rec2md
        rec2md = True
        rec2m = canvas.create_rectangle(100, 0, 200, 100, fill='red')
        canvas.move(rec2m, 200, 150)
        canvas.delete(rec2)
        root.after(1000, firstmove)
        movesd += 1
    else:
        if secondgo == True:
            global movesd
            global rec2md
            rec2md = True
            rec2m = canvas.create_rectangle(100, 0, 200, 100, fill='red')
            canvas.move(rec2m, 200, 150)
            canvas.delete(rec2)
            root.after(1000, secondmove)
            movesd += 1

def r3m(event):
    combinations()
    if firstmovedone == False:
        global movesd
        global rec3md
        rec3md = True
        rec3m = canvas.create_rectangle(100, 0, 200, 100, fill='red')
        canvas.move(rec3m, 300, 150)
        canvas.delete(rec3)
        root.after(1000, firstmove)
    else:
        if secondgo == True:
            global movesd
            global rec3md
            rec3md = True
            rec3m = canvas.create_rectangle(100, 0, 200, 100, fill='red')
            canvas.move(rec3m, 300, 150)
            canvas.delete(rec3)
            root.after(1000, secondmove)
            movesd += 1
        else:
            if thirdgo == True:
                global rec3md
                rec3md = True
                rec3m = canvas.create_rectangle(100, 0, 200, 100, fill='red')
                canvas.move(rec3m, 300, 150)
                canvas.delete(rec3)
                root.after(1000, thirdmove)
                movesd += 1

def r4m(event):
    combinations()
    if firstmovedone == False:
        global movesd
        global rec4md
        rec4md = True
        rec4m = canvas.create_rectangle(100, 0, 200, 100, fill='red')
        canvas.move(rec4m, 100, 250)
        canvas.delete(rec4)
        root.after(1000, firstmove)
        movesd += 1
    else:
        if secondgo == True:
            global movesd
            global rec4md
            rec4md = True
            rec4m = canvas.create_rectangle(100, 0, 200, 100, fill='red')
            canvas.move(rec4m, 100, 250)
            canvas.delete(rec4)
            root.after(1000, secondmove)
            movesd += 1
        else:
            if thirdgo == True:
                global movesd
                global rec4md
                rec4md = True
                rec4m = canvas.create_rectangle(100, 0, 200, 100, fill='red')
                canvas.move(rec4m, 300, 250)
                canvas.delete(rec4)
                root.after(1000, fourthmove)
                movesd += 1

def r5m(event):
    combinations()
    if firstmovedone == False:
        global movesd
        global rec5md
        rec5md = True
        rec5m = canvas.create_rectangle(100, 0, 200, 100, fill='red')
        canvas.move(rec5m, 200, 250)
        canvas.delete(rec5)
        root.after(1000, firstmove)
        movesd += 1
    else:
        if secondgo == True:
            global movesd
            global rec5md
            rec5md = True
            rec5m = canvas.create_rectangle(100, 0, 200, 100, fill='red')
            canvas.move(rec5m, 200, 250)
            canvas.delete(rec5)
            root.after(1000, secondmove)
            movesd += 1
        else:
            if thirdgo == True:
                global movesd
                global rec5md
                rec5md = True
                rec5m = canvas.create_rectangle(100, 0, 200, 100, fill='red')
                canvas.move(rec5m, 300, 250)
                canvas.delete(rec5)
                root.after(1000, thirdmove)
                movesd += 1

def r6m(event):
    combinations()
    if firstmovedone == False:
        global movesd
        global rec5md
        rec6md = True
        rec6m = canvas.create_rectangle(100, 0, 200, 100, fill='red')
        canvas.move(rec6m, 300, 250)
        canvas.delete(rec6)
        root.after(1000, firstmove)
        movesd += 1
    else:
        if secondgo == True:
            global movesd
            global rec6md
            rec6md = True
            rec6m = canvas.create_rectangle(100, 0, 200, 100, fill='red')
            canvas.move(rec6m, 300, 250)
            canvas.delete(rec6)
            root.after(1000, secondmove)
            movesd += 1
        else:
            if thirdgo == True:
                global movesd
                global rec6md
                rec6md = True
                rec6m = canvas.create_rectangle(100, 0, 200, 100, fill='red')
                canvas.move(rec6m, 300, 250)
                canvas.delete(rec6)
                root.after(1000, thirdmove)
                movesd += 1

def r7m(event):
    combinations()
    if firstmovedone == False:
        global movesd
        global rec7md
        rec7md = True
        rec7m = canvas.create_rectangle(100, 0, 200, 100, fill='red')
        canvas.move(rec7m, 100, 350)
        canvas.delete(rec7)
        root.after(1000, firstmove)
        movesd += 1
    else:
        if secondgo == True:
            global movesd
            global rec7md
            rec7md = True
            rec7m = canvas.create_rectangle(100, 0, 200, 100, fill='red')
            canvas.move(rec7m, 100, 350)
            canvas.delete(rec7)
            root.after(1000, secondmove)
            movesd += 1
        else:
            if thirdgo == True:
                global movesd
                global rec7md
                rec7md = True
                rec7m = canvas.create_rectangle(100, 0, 200, 100, fill='red')
                canvas.move(rec7m, 100, 350)
                canvas.delete(rec7)
                root.after(1000, thirdmove)
                movesd += 1

def r8m(event):
    combinations()
    if firstmovedone == False:
        global movesd
        global rec8md
        rec8md = True
        rec8m = canvas.create_rectangle(100, 0, 200, 100, fill='red')
        canvas.move(rec8m, 200, 350)
        canvas.delete(rec8)
        root.after(1000, firstmove)
        movesd += 1
    else:
        if secondgo == True:
            global movesd
            global rec8md
            rec8md = True
            rec8m = canvas.create_rectangle(100, 0, 200, 100, fill='red')
            canvas.move(rec8m, 200, 350)
            canvas.delete(rec8)
            root.after(1000, secondmove)
            movesd += 1
        else:
            if thirdgo == True:
                global movesd
                global rec8md
                rec8md = True
                rec8m = canvas.create_rectangle(100, 0, 200, 100, fill='red')
                canvas.move(rec8m, 200, 350)
                canvas.delete(rec8)
                root.after(1000, thirdmove)
                movesd += 1

def r9m(event):
    combinations()
    global movesd
    if firstmovedone == False:
        global rec9md
        rec9md = True
        rec9m = canvas.create_rectangle(100, 0, 200, 100, fill='red')
        canvas.move(rec9m, 300, 350)
        canvas.delete(rec9)
        root.after(1000, firstmove)
        movesd += 1
    else:
        if secondgo == True:
            global rec9md
            rec9md = True
            rec9m = canvas.create_rectangle(100, 0, 200, 100, fill='red')
            canvas.move(rec9m, 300, 350)
            canvas.delete(rec9)
            root.after(1000, secondmove)
            movesd += 1
        else:
            if thirdgo == True:
                global rec9md
                rec9md = True
                rec9m = canvas.create_rectangle(100, 0, 200, 100, fill='red')
                canvas.move(rec9m, 300, 350)
                canvas.delete(rec9)
                root.after(1000, thirdmove)
                movesd += 1

done = False

canvas.tag_bind(rec1, "<ButtonPress-1>", r1m)
canvas.tag_bind(rec2, "<ButtonPress-1>", r2m)
canvas.tag_bind(rec3, "<ButtonPress-1>", r3m)
canvas.tag_bind(rec4, "<ButtonPress-1>", r4m)
canvas.tag_bind(rec5, "<ButtonPress-1>", r5m)
canvas.tag_bind(rec6, "<ButtonPress-1>", r6m)
canvas.tag_bind(rec7, "<ButtonPress-1>", r7m)
canvas.tag_bind(rec8, "<ButtonPress-1>", r8m)
canvas.tag_bind(rec9, "<ButtonPress-1>", r9m)

mainloop()
```

Long code, yes. In the function `combinations`, I tried setting the window to 'You Win' when the player surpasses 3 goes, but as I suspected, this is not how the game works. To sum up, I want to know how to recognise a pattern without typing up the 120 possible combinations. Thanks for your time :)

Comment: Would it be possible to minimize your code to a state such that your problem is reproducible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To win at the **Tic Tac Toe** game, the player has to align 3 marks in horizontal, in vertical or in diagonal. The proposed algorithm is only focused to count the number of marks placed by the player and declare the winner when counter is 3 (`if movesd == 3:` in the function `combinations()`).

To compute the state of the board after each move, it is necessary to replace the use of `rec1md = False` to `rec9md = False` switching to True by a complete view of the board `recmd = [..]` filled by `' '`=free, `'R'`=red player and `'B'`=blue player:

**Step 1** - use a new state of board = array of 9 cells

```
# all cases of the board are initialized to ' '=free
recmd = [ ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']
#rec1md = False
#rec2md = False
...
#rec9md = False
```

**Step 2** - update each `rec<X>md` by the `recmd[<X-1>]`.

In the `firstmove()`, `secondmove()` and `thirdmove()` functions.

```
if firstrandom == "rm1":
    if (recmd[0] != ' '): # is the case still marked ?
        firstmove()
    else:
        rec1mf = canvas.create_rectangle(100, 0, 200, 100, fill='blue')
        canvas.move(rec1mf, 100, 150)
        recmd[0] = 'B' # to mark the case as 'B'=blue player
```

In the `r1m(event)`, ... and `r9m(event)` functions.

```
global recmd # rec1md
if firstmovedone == False:
    recmd[0] = 'R' # instead of  rec1md = True
    rec1m = canvas.create_rectangle(100, 0, 200, 100, fill='red')
    canvas.move(rec1m, 100, 150)
    canvas.delete(rec1)
```

**Step 3** - create the checking function `boardstate(recmd)`.

The function returns on of the following states: `'INPROG'`= game in progress, `'WIN'`= the human (RED player) is the winner, `'LOSE'`= the computer (BLUE player) is the winner & `'NULL'`= no winner.

**1-** check if one row is filled by `R` or `B`.

```
for i in range(0,3):
    # rows
    if ((recmd[(i*3)+0]=='R') and (recmd[(i*3)+1]=='R') and (recmd[(i*3)+2]=='R')):
        print("Win in row[%d]." % (i+1))
        return ('WIN')
    if ((recmd[(i*3)+0]=='B') and (recmd[(i*3)+1]=='B') and (recmd[(i*3)+2]=='B')):
        print("Lose in row[%d]." % (i+1))
        return ('LOSE')
```

**2-** check if one column is filled by `R` or `B`.

```
for i in range(0,3):
    #column
    if ((recmd[i+0]=='R') and (recmd[i+3]=='R') and (recmd[i+6]=='R')):
        print("Win in col[%d]." % (i+1))
        return ('WIN')
    if ((recmd[i+0]=='B') and (recmd[i+3]=='B') and (recmd[i+6]=='B')):
        print("Lose in col[%d]." % (i+1))
        return ('LOSE')
```

**3-** check if one diagonal is filled by `R` or `B`.

```
#diagonal
if ((recmd[0]=='R') and (recmd[4]=='R') and (recmd[8]=='R')):
    print("Win in diagonal.")
    return ('WIN')
if ((recmd[0]=='B') and (recmd[4]=='B') and (recmd[8]=='B')):
    print("Lose in diagonal.")
    return ('LOSE')
if ((recmd[6]=='R') and (recmd[4]=='R') and (recmd[2]=='R')):
    print("Win in diagonal.")
    return ('WIN')
if ((recmd[6]=='B') and (recmd[4]=='B') and (recmd[2]=='B')):
    print("Lose in diagonal.")
    return ('LOSE')
```

**4-** check if the board is full (no `' '` found)

```
if (' ' in recmd):
    return ('INPROG')
return ('NULL')
```

**Step 4** - update the function `combinations()` to manage the `boardstate()` function.

```
def combinations():
    global done
    global recmd
    iswin = boardstate(recmd)
    print('boardstate = %s' % (iswin))
    # if (movesd >= 3) and (done == False):
    if (iswin != 'INPROG') and (done == False):
```

**ADDED N°1 >>>>**

**Step 5** - move (or add) the call of `combinations()` at the end of function.

To compute the correct state in the `combinations()`, it shall be called after updating `recmd[..]` cell on the function `firstmove()`, ..., `thirdmove()`.

And also, for each function `r1m(event)` to `r9m(event)`, add a call to the `combinations()` function to warn the player just after.

> The call of `combinations()` has to be added at the **END** of each
>   `r1m(event)` to `r9m(event)` functions.

**ADDED N°2 >>>>**

**Step 6** - manage the end of the game and other update.

> When the condition `if (iswin != 'INPROG') and (done == False)` is
>   True, you can check who is the winner and set `done` to `True`.

```
if (iswin != 'INPROG') and (done == False):
    print("test")
    done = True
    if (iswin == 'WIN'):
        print("Congratulation you Win !!!")
    elif (iswin == 'LOSE'):
        print("Sorry you Lose !!!")
    else:
        print("No winner, game over !!!")
```

Then, to prevent retry in the `firstmove()` function, it is necessary to stop the `random.choice(moves)` loop by overwriting the `firstrandom` when `done == True`. Don't forget to declare `global done` at the beginning of the function.

> To stay in the `firstmove()` function, keep the `firstmovedone ==
>   False` by removing the `firstmovedone = True`

```
def firstmove():
    global secondgo
    global firstmovedone
    # firstmovedone = True
    global recmd
    global done
    moves = ["rm1", "rm2", "rm3", "rm4", "rm5", "rm6", "rm7", "rm8", "rm9"]
    firstrandom = random.choice(moves)
    if (done == True):
        firstrandom = "end" # don't select a move
    if firstrandom == "rm1":
        if (recmd[0] != ' '): # is the case still marked ?
            firstmove()
        else:
            rec1mf = canvas.create_rectangle(100, 0, 200, 100, fill='blue')
            canvas.move(rec1mf, 100, 150)
            recmd[0] = 'B'
    ...
```

Comment: When I executed this code, I had a reoccurring error which told me that there was something wrong with `firstmove()`. Here's what happened: [link](http://i.gyazo.com/d0d2c5393bffdec65d7fb5d1a4ac9b5d.png)

Comment: Could you show what look like one of line numbers in error (with neighbor lines) or the edit your question to append the update function `firstmove()` ?

Comment: Did modify the declaration in the function `firstmove()` ==> `global recmd` instead of `global rec1md` ?

Comment: Nevermind that first error, now I have the problem that nothing is happening after I use my firstmove. For example, when I click on a square, blue should then 'click' on a square, but that does not happen. I can send you a link of my code if needed.

Comment: @jakethefake, Yes send me a link to your source code and after I will update my answer (the list of changes is very long)

Comment: How should I send all my code to you; it's about 600 lines long :/

Comment: You can use something like PASTEBIN to share your source code.

Comment: In my answer **Step 2**, I wrote _"update each `rec<X>md` by the `recmd[<X-1>]`"_. That's meaning _"lines with `rec1md` become `recmd[0]`, ... lines with `rec9md` become `recmd[8]`"_. Also remove `movesd` (no more used) and check if each function using `recmd[..]` as a `global recmd` on top.

Comment: @jakethefake, just also added the complementary **Step 5**.

Comment: Problem is that when I have 3 in a row, it doesn't recognise it. Also, 'blue' often replaces my red rectangles. Here's my code: [link](http://pastebin.com/yVDM1P3f)

Comment: All of the steps have been completed, and I still have problems; though I do appreciate you taking your time to help me :)

Comment: Did your problem arrived when your board is complete ? In the `combinations()`, did you see `"test"' ?

Comment: No, it doesn't seem to call the function though I did add `combinations()` to the start of `r1m - r9m` :/

Comment: If possible, if you've tried and executed this code, could you send me an exact link of the code you executed?

Comment: You shall add `combinations()` at the end of the `r1m()` ... `r9m()` functions. Giving the final source code will be not pedagogical !!! In fact, to get a fully functional game, I have simplify the algorithm by removing `secondmove()` and `thirdmove()` and cutting the part in `r1m()` ... `r9m()` functions. And when detected the end of game `if (iswin != 'INPROG') and (done == False):`, you have to assign `done = True`. I will add **`Step 6`**.

Comment: I'm honestly sorry if I'm frustrating you, but the game itself is not recognising when I get 3 in a row. I've shown you my code, so I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Sorry for your time.

Comment: I think there's something wrong with `(recmd[8] != ' ')`, it doesn't recognise an output...

Comment: Check my **ADDED N°2 >>>**. And also replace the `mainloop()` at the end of the program by `root.mainloop()`.

Comment: As I thought, nothing works. So is it not possible that you can show me the code that should infact work according to the steps used above? Otherwise, I feel like giving up :/

Comment: Here is the link to a functional ["TicTacToe game"](http://pastebin.com/ka2i7MRc)...

Comment: Well except the part of blue still taking over a square red already owns, I guess thats as good as its gonna get, so for the sake of the purpose, thanks, you 'answered' my question.

Comment: My answer was long as your question, especially the source code, was long. It should be more efficient to spend time to analyse your need before coding a so long source code without using for-loop and array management.